# React change parent array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, parent-child

In the parent component `manage-categories.jsx` I have an array declared `categoryTypes`

```
const categoryTypes = [
    { name: "category", values: props.categories, active: true },
    { name: "type", values: props.types },
    { name: "finish", values: props.finishes },
    { name: "profile", values: props.profiles },
    { name: "thickness", values: props.thicknesses },
    { name: "ral", values: props.rals },
  ];
```

and a function `selectItem` that is called in the child component `category-types-card.jsx`

```
const selectItem = (item, category) => {
    switch (category.name) {
      case "category":
        setSelectedCategoryItem(item);
        break;
      case "type":
        setSelectedTypeItem(item);
        break;
      case "finish":
        setSelectedFinishItem(item);
        break;
      case "profile":
        setSelectedProfileItem(item);
        break;
      case "thickness":
        setSelectedThicknessItem(item);
        break;
      case "ral":
        setSelectedRalItem(item);
    }
  };
```

In the child component I need to show something for the categories that have `active: true` Category becomes active when it has an selectedItem.

I tried to make it active like `categoryTypes[1] = { ...categoryTypes[1], active: true };` in the above switch, but in the child component the active property does not change for the certain category.

Calling the child component:

```
<Row className="mb-4">
        {categoryTypes.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <Colxx
              xxs="12"
              xs="6"
              sm="6"
              md="6"
              lg="4"
              xl="4"
              xxl="4"
              key={index}
            >
              <CategoryTypes
                category={category}
                employee={employee}
                selectItem={selectItem}
                selectedCategoryItem={selectedCategoryItem}
                selectedTypeItem={selectedTypeItem}
                selectedFinishItem={selectedFinishItem}
                selectedProfileItem={selectedProfileItem}
                selectedThicknessItem={selectedThicknessItem}
                selectedRalItem={selectedRalItem}
              />
            </Colxx>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
```

How should I handle correctly this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to have the `active` property inside the `props.categories`

Comment: I tried now, it doesn't work

Comment: @simpller Could you please post some more code? At least show how you render the child component and pass it the props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing a callback to the child component? Like so:

```js
const ManageCategories = (props) => {
  const [categoryTypes, setCategoryTypes] = useState([
    { name: "category", values: props.categories, active: true },
    { name: "type", values: props.types },
    { name: "finish", values: props.finishes },
    { name: "profile", values: props.profiles },
    { name: "thickness", values: props.thicknesses },
    { name: "ral", values: props.rals },
  ])

  const setCategoryTypeActive = (categoryName, active) => {
    setCategoryTypes((categoryTypes) =>
      categoryTypes.map((categoryType) =>
        categoryType.name === categoryName
          ? { ...categoryType, active }
          : categoryType
      )
    )
  }

  return (
    <Row className="mb-4">
      {categoryTypes.map((category, index) => (
        <Colxx xxs="12" xs="6" sm="6" md="6" lg="4" xl="4" xxl="4" key={index}>
          <CategoryTypes
            category={category}
            employee={employee}
            selectItem={selectItem}
            selectedCategoryItem={selectedCategoryItem}
            selectedTypeItem={selectedTypeItem}
            selectedFinishItem={selectedFinishItem}
            selectedProfileItem={selectedProfileItem}
            selectedThicknessItem={selectedThicknessItem}
            selectedRalItem={selectedRalItem}
            setCategoryTypeActive={setCategoryTypeActive}
          />
        </Colxx>
      ))}
    </Row>
  )
}
```

Then, somewhere in your child component, for example:

```js
const CategoryTypesCard = (props) => {
  props.setCategoryTypeActive("finish", true)

  // ...
}
```